# Why does $(n-1)(n−2)\cdots(n−)+(n−1)(−2)\cdots(−+1)= (−1)(−2)\cdots(−+1)(−+)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Why is it equal?
$$(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k)+k(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1)=(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1)(n-k+k)?$$

I tried common factor and algebra tricks.

What is done here?

I have tried common factor but it doesn't help.

Comment: `tried common factor` What happened when you factored out $(n-1)(n-2)\ldots(n-k+1)\,$?

Comment: For k = 1, it does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
LHS
& = \pmb{(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1)}(n-k) + k\pmb{(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1)} \\
& = \pmb{(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1)}[(n-k)+k] \\
& = (n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1)(n-k+k) \\
& = RHS
\end{align}

The **bold** part is the common factor.